# Why doesn't tap-clicking work often in Flash?

Tags: adobe-flash

In a few situations in Flash, tapping to click doesn't work, while mechanically clicking does. (Tap-clicking is of course turned on.) It's in some cases a Flash game, and in some cases Hulu or another video site. Why doesn't tapping work, and why *does* clicking work?

My guess is that it has something to do with whatever the Flash equivalent is of "mouse *down*" versus "mouse *clicked*."

Comment: When you say "tapping", what input device are you referring to? A Magic Trackpad?

Comment: @djacobson The trackpad on my MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably about that Flash object's design/development.

I haven't used Flash for development in a long time, but it must have attributes for allowing/disallowing such things. And since every developer behaves differently you are experiencing different things like that.

Comment: The "tap to click" feature doesn't mean a different thing as far as programs are concerned though—as far as a program can tell, a click and a tap are the same thing. The OS interprets the user's input.